# How to remove a branch but keep the orphaned with the same name?

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging, githooks, github-pages

I have a Python project where the documentation is in an orphaned `gh-pages` branch which I created by following [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/brantfaircloth/791759). There is a `doc/build/html` folder in the project where the docs get compiled and where the `gh-pages` branch is checked out.

Now, I accidentally executed the `git checkout gh-pages` command in the project root, which created a new `gh-pages` branch and now it seems that I have two of them. One orphaned and one normal. Is it so?

How do I remove the normal `gh-pages` branch but keep the orphaned one?

Comment: `git checkout gh-pages` shouldn't create a new branch. Why do you think there are two branches?

Comment: Cause when I executed the command there was a message that a new `gh-pages` branch was created. And when I push to GItHub from master I get a conflict message.

Comment: Do you mean you executed `git checkout -b gh-pages`?

Comment: well, I'm not sure because I discovered the consequences maybe a week after I executed the command.

Comment: My usual workflow was to compile the docs, then `cd` to `doc/build/html` where the whole repository is cloned and the `gh-pages` branch is always checked out and from there I execute `git push origin gh-pages`. Then, one day I accidentally checked out `gh-pages` from the root dir.

Comment: It's not really clear from your question which folders are under source control, whether there are multiple repositories, etc. etc. Fortunately that hasn't stopped janos answering ...

Comment: @Useless Yes, I know. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happened is you created a local branch called `gh-pages`. It has nothing to do with the the `gh-pages` branch that exists on your GitHub account, it's just a branch with the same name. (And this is why you get a conflict when you try to push this to GitHub: the two branches have nothing to do with each other.)

You can delete your local branch safely with:

```
git branch -d gh-pages
```

This command is always safe, because it will only delete a branch if all the commits in it exist in another local branch. You cannot accidentally delete an orphaned branch with it. (Don't confuse it with `-D`, that's the one that will delete branches even if it has unmerged unique commits.)

Btw, maybe this is the command you were looking for in the first place:

```
git checkout --track origin/gh-pages
# or in older versions of Git:
#git checkout -b gh-pages origin/gh-pages
```

This creates a local branch called `gh-pages` from the `gh-pages` branch at your origin (= GitHub). What you actually did was you created a local branch called `gh-pages` based on your current branch, probably `master`, NOT based on a remote branch.

Comment: `git checkout --track origin/gh-pages` should be sufficient, btw.